# Sidekiq transient vs fatal errors

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Is there a way to err from a Sidekiq job in a way that tells Sidekiq that "this error is fatal and unrecoverable, do not retry, send it straight to dead job queue"?

Looking at [Sidekiq Error Handling](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling) documentation, it seems like it interpret all errors as transient, and will retry a job (if retry is enabled) regardless of the error type.

Comment: Maybe the answers on [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2072) issue could help you?

Comment: @JeroenHeier One of the comments on the issue you linked is exactly what  I want: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2072#issuecomment-160832087

Comment: @JeroenHeier Would you mind posting it was an Answer, so that I can mark it as Accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2072#issuecomment-160832087) a solution for your problem. In that post they suggested to write a custom middleware that handles the exceptions you want to prevent retries for. This is a basic example:

```
def call(worker, msg, queue)
  begin
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    msg['retry'] = false
    raise
  end
end
```

You can extending that you get:

```
def call(worker, msg, queue)
  begin
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    msg['retry'] = false
    raise
  rescue Exception => e
    if worker.respond_to?(:handle_error)
      worker.handle_error(e)
    else
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should rescue those specific errors and not re-raise them.

```
def perform
  call_something
rescue CustomException
  nil
end
```

Edit:

Well, if you want to purposely send a message to the DLQ/DJQ, you'd need to make a method that does what [`#send_to_morgue`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/1a039f570805a9d1b275a167f30a8821718ec59d/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L151-L162) does. I'm sure Mike Perham is going to come in here and yell at me for suggesting this but...

```
    def send_to_morgue(msg)
      Sidekiq.logger.info { "Adding dead #{msg['class']} job #{msg['jid']}" }
      payload = Sidekiq.dump_json(msg)
      now = Time.now.to_f
      Sidekiq.redis do |conn|
        conn.multi do
          conn.zadd('dead', now, payload)
          conn.zremrangebyscore('dead', '-inf', now - DeadSet.timeout)
          conn.zremrangebyrank('dead', 0, -DeadSet.max_jobs)
        end
      end
    end
```

The only difference you'd have to dig into what `msg` looks like going into that method but I suspect it's what normally hits the middleware before parse.

Comment: `nil` is redundant :)

Comment: @mudasobwa agreed but I put it there so it's explicit

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not send the message to the Dead Job Queue, which is an important part of the workflow I want for "fatal" errors.

Comment: I missed that part @mtulio, thanks for clarifying.  Sadly the [`#send_to_morgue`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/1a039f570805a9d1b275a167f30a8821718ec59d/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L151-L162) method is private